# Scrolling Texture bug on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

currently im trying to implement a shader that scrolls a texture for my loading screen.
I am facing an issue where the texture is getting kind of stretched.
This is only happening on Android, ios and pc is fine, has anyone an idea why this is happening?

[This is happening](https://gifyu.com/image/SCu6V)

[ShaderGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VepO6.png)

[Texture in Use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBtzP.png)

I tried using other textures aswell but it happened there also.